# Sklearn.metrics' classification_report gives 'Mix type not allowed' error

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-learn

I'm trying to call this:

```
  le = LabelEncoder()
  ...
  print(classification_report(le.transform(test.target), predict, target_names=name))
```

but I get the error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py", line 1358, in classification_report
labels = unique_labels(y_true, y_pred)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/multiclass.py", line 85, in unique_labels
raise ValueError("Mix type of y not allowed, got types %s" % ys_types)
ValueError: Mix type of y not allowed, got types set(['continuous', 'multiclass'])
```

Not sure what Mix is the problem, I verified that all three variables I'm passing in, test.target, predict, and name are all as I would expect:

```
test.target:
['person_016' 'person_001' 'person_005' 'person_004' 'person_020'
'person_016' 'person_016' 'person_020' 'person_025' 'person_004'
 ...
'person_026' 'person_014' 'person_001']

predict:
[19.575590459940518, 19.839395514422097, 20.43425378901069, 19.964017992452884, 21.45376122802073, 18.712636990625406, 21.125694301335812, 21.742956909079584, 19.037879735668064, 20.816300827583323, 19.64423095622044, 19.010704735361116, 18.95323662846389, 17.46634955187493, 16.934430341623507, 22.966209040805335, 19.639052959811657, 19.706177567678345, 19.006011547672394, 19.320013835415892, 20.44412117907493, 20.825497343759864, 20.726555900613654, 19.672513651300203, 19.9491013835408, 21.01214872400199, 18.69471797641691, 20.082105810508747, 20.122244287061566, 20.06319587011585, 18.705927427073064, 20.328460707835234, 20.413808229995986, 21.014453739539434, 20.54868136915643, 20.819321691849094, 20.61430646584199, 17.453817874157497, 19.743240932983102, 19.22964382699397, 20.311496680276196, 17.852724433410376, 20.630922279852285, 19.976928038942354, 18.807012607768115, 19.83117772911092, 20.461658112464125, 19.519698587584386, 20.70975054257962, 20.132911911054013, 18.257004232666407, 19.66136365688736, 17.462129105967588, 18.491388123042743, 19.32200515520864, 17.950456059223825, 19.39461652294937, 20.61770528643103, 19.235062932525405, 19.57239776039756, 20.941671943932267, 17.194912409732282, 19.92346685191489]

name:
['person_009' 'person_025' 'person_020' 'person_015' 'person_001'
'person_004' 'person_026' 'person_001' 'person_005' 'person_023'
  ... 
 'person_014' 'person_001']
```

Comment: What is `predict`? `le.transform(test.target)` is a list of numbers and `predict` apparently is a list of strings. You ask `classification_report` to compare apples to oranges.

Comment: The predict is the array of numbers, while test.target and name are the strings.  Sorry, I've updated the output